# Orientation Keyboard Movement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, rotation

Here are some great tutorials on *portrait* textfield movement.

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220818/moving-uiview-up-when-keyboard-shown)
[Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field)

My View, on the other hand, rotates to both portrait and landscape, and in both orientations the keyboard obscures the textfield...  Right now, both portrait, and **One** of the landscape orientations work.

So I'm wondering how I can include both landscape orientations.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif{
 if ([serverIP isFirstResponder]){
    if (isPortrait && self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0){
        [self setViewMovedVertical:YES];
    }
    else if (!isPortrait && self.view.frame.origin.x >= 0){
        [self setViewMovedHorizontal:YES];
    }
 }
}
```

**To move the view. Here are the corrosponding methods**

```
#define PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF 216
#define LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF 140

-(void) setViewMovedVertical:(BOOL)movedUp{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

 CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

 if (movedUp){
     rect.origin.y -= PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
     rect.size.height += PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
 }
 else{
     rect.origin.y += PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
     rect.size.height -= PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
 }

 self.view.frame = rect;

 [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) setViewMovedHorizontal:(BOOL)moved{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; 

 CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

 if (moved){
     rect.origin.x -= LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
     rect.size.width += LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
 }
 else{
     rect.origin.x += LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
     rect.size.width -= LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
 }

 self.view.frame = rect;

 [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

**And here's the method to move it back down**

```
-(IBAction) serverIPDone: (UITextField *) sender{
if ([serverIP isFirstResponder]){
 if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0){
    [self setViewMovedVertical:NO];
 }
 if (self.view.frame.origin.x < 0){
    [self setViewMovedHorizontal:NO];   
 }
 [serverIP resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Hope you can help! If I've anti-disambiguated (see what I did there?) the question, please let me know!

Comment: not sure how both landscapes dont work..they will use the same code..interesting. good question

Comment: I figured that both would work. It's somewhat frustrating =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINALLY** Figured it out!!!!

Here's what was wrong: The origin did indeed change between the two landscape modes. So all you have to do is detect which version of landscape you are in, and add or subtract based on that!

```
-(IBAction) serverIPDone: (UITextField *) sender{
if ([serverIP isFirstResponder]){
        if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0){
            [self setViewMovedVertical:NO];
        }
    if (self.view.frame.origin.x != 0){
        [self setViewMovedHorizontal:NO];   
    }
    [serverIP resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

**The previous** makes sure that the keyboard is unset.

```
-(void) setViewMovedVertical:(BOOL)movedUp{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

if (movedUp){
    rect.origin.y -= PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
    rect.size.height += PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
}
else{
    rect.origin.y += PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
    rect.size.height -= PORTRAIT_KEY_OFF;
}

self.view.frame = rect;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) setViewMovedHorizontal:(BOOL)moved{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; 

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

if (moved){
    if (leftLandscape)
        rect.origin.x -= LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
    else
        rect.origin.x += LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
}
else{
    if (leftLandscape)
        rect.origin.x += LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
    else
        rect.origin.x -= LANDSCAPE_KEY_OFF;
    NSLog(@"after: %f",rect.origin.x);

}

self.view.frame = rect;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

**The Previous** will do the actual movement of the keyboard. I got rid of the resizing, you can add it back in.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)x     
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(x)) {
    isPortrait = TRUE;  
} 
else { 
    isPortrait = FALSE;
            leftLandscape = (x == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); 
}

}
```

**The Previous** will make sure you set the variables isPortrait and leftLandscape correctly.

*It took too long, but I'm finally* **DONE**!!!